# Creating requirements.txt in GitLab

Tags: python, git, gitlab, virtualenv, requirements

Probably a silly question, but I am trying to set up a project in GitLab that is going to be used for deployment of an ML model, for which I will use FastAPI. I'm very new to this and will try to provide as much info as possible.

I created the project in GitLab, which right now only contains a README.md file. The actual Python code is stored in a folder on my computer ("MyProject"), which contains two folders, each of which containing some data, .py scripts and a notebook.

To set up `requirements.txt`, I tried to create a virtual environment in Windows. Now, when I open the "MyProject" folder, it contains those two folders with code and the virtual enviroment, which also contains `Lib, Scripts, pyvenv.cfg`. The latter contains:

```
home = c:\users\me\anaconda3
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.8.5.final.0
virtualenv = 20.10.0
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = c:\users\me\anaconda3
base-exec-prefix = c:\users\me\anaconda3
base-executable = c:\users\me\anaconda3\python.exe
```

I also cloned the GitLab repo, but on my computer it is saved somewhere else (in `c:\users\me`). I know that I need to do:

```
pip install -r
requirements.txt
```

But I don't understand how to actually add this requirements file. All of the packages and libraries that I needed for my ML model were installed a long time ago with anaconda, before I created this virtual environment. Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Why not simply `pip freeze > requirements.txt`?

Comment: What libraries do you use?

Comment: @NilsWerner I did this while being in the environment, in anaconda prompt, and the file that was created is empty.

Comment: What you might have done wrong is not using a virtual environment in the first place. But that just means a little extra work. Which way do you want to go: start fresh and add packages or start from you anaconda setup and clean up the undesired requirements?

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm using like  dozens of different libraries, from `pandas` to `nltk` and `spacy`.

Comment: @KlausD. So if the libraries are in my system, and the code ran well, there is no way of getting those libraries to the environment?

Comment: What the answers below are missing: You have to `deactivate` the virtual environment and use your anaconda setup  for `pip freeze` to work. After that have a look at the created file and remove any package you do not need in the environment. Then activate the venv again and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: @KlausD. I think this is the closest that I got to the solution. I now only need to select the needed libraries out of this long list haha. Another noob question, but would the fact that I created the environment now and not before setting up these folders with code affect me in any other way?

Comment: `pandas to nltk and spacy` create an empty file `requirements.txt` with your editor and add one library per line. `pandas` on one line, `mtk` on another, `spacy` on the third line. Repeat for each library that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mixed up some things. GitLab uses Git for version control of your files (your code). Therefore your repository should contain the files with your code. You can just put the files of your folder "MyProject" into the folder, where you cloned the repository to. Also add the requirements.txt the readme-file and so on.

The virtual environment is used to keep your system installation of Python clean and only have the necessary packages installed for each project. Among other things to avoid package requirement conflicts. The usage of an requirements.txt file is independet of the virtual environment, even if it is a sensible combination.

In general this means, your requirements.txt is always shared together with your code, because it lays within the same repository. When someone clones the repository, he can use the requirements.txt to install all the dependencies to his venv (or somewherer else) and then run your code without the nedd to install further python packages.

Your requirements.txt file has to contain columns, which look like this: `numpy==1.21.4`. Then you have to activate the environment with `<your path to the venv folder>\venv\Scripts\activate` and use `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the packages listed in your requirements.txt.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution would be `pip freeze > requirements.txt` but this command will add all the packages present in your enviroment which may not be used in your project. In my daily job, I use this https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/. you can install it and run `pipreqs --force` in your project folder. This will add packages to requirements.txt which are used in your project.

Comment: Yeah, using pip freeze just creates an empty folder. So that means that I leave this empty file as it is, but I install `pipreqs` within the environment, and run `pipreqs --force` in "MyProject"?

Comment: please give it a try

Comment: I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 454: character maps to <undefined>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `requirements.txt` using `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and add it to your repo. This will generate list of your installed packages and exact versions you have.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/

Comment: I did this, as the other commenter suggested, but the file that got created is empty.

Comment: If you pip freeze is empty, that means you haven't installed any packages (in this env). Ensure that you are using correct virtualenv.

Comment: Would it help if I just manually install them now, or do I need to start afresh? I should have created the environment first...

Comment: You could create a new environment and install needed packages, if you know what you need. You are using conda, maybe you'll find your initial env using `conda env list` and then `conda activate <envname>`?

Answer (score 0):

> how to actually add this requirements file

You create the file yourself. For every library that you use, add a line in `requirements.txt` with the name of the library.  Also see documentation https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/

After creating the file, `commit` and `push` it to the git repository.

> All of the packages and libraries that I needed for my ML model were installed a long time ago with anaconda

Gitlab-CI with docker executor starts with a fresh environment. You have to repeat *all* installation steps that you did on your workstation *inside* the docker environment. You can run docker instance of the container locally for testing. Consult gitalb-ci and docker documentations.